# Maven POM relativePath with environment

Tags: maven, environment-variables, parent, relative-path

i want to use in my child's pom.xml an environment variable like ${my_project.id} in the .
e.g. `<relativePath>../../build/${my_project.id}/pom.xml</relativePath>`

If I use the value of the variable it works, but i want to use the variable.

The error is "and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 6, column 13"

Is that possible?

Thanks and regards